# Solving $a\sin \theta + b\cos \theta + c\sin 2\theta + d\cos 2\theta = k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to solve (for $\theta$) an equation of the form:

$$a\sin \theta + b\cos \theta + c\sin 2\theta + d\cos 2\theta = k$$

I'm only interested in real-valued solutions where $0 ≤ \theta ≤ \frac\pi4$, if one exists, and also knowing if none exist.
Also, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $k$ are rational numbers.

Is there an "easy" way to attack this problem?

The only strategy I could come up with to express all sines and cosines
as $\sin \theta$, and then square the equation to get rid of square roots, and then solve a quartic equation, and then check the legitimacy of the roots.
Is there an easier approach, perhaps one that is more customized to this problem?

Comment: You can combine $a\sin\theta + b\cos\theta$ into a single function $m\sin(\theta+\phi)$, where $m=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\phi=\text{atan2}(b,a)$. (See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations) on trigonometric identities.) You can similarly combine the two terms with $2\theta$.

Comment: You can distill this to a quartic very directly by expanding the double-angle terms and using the so-called [Weierstrass substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution): $$\sin\theta = \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \qquad \cos\theta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ where $t=\tan(\theta/2)$. Clearing $(1+t^2)^2$ from the denominator, the quartic is $$ t^4 (b- d+k) -2t^3(a -2 c)  + 2t^2(3 d + k) -2t(a +2 c )+ k - b - d= 0$$ (although you should probably double-check my algebra). Analyzing potential solutions remains difficult, however.

Comment: In fact, this is a general quartic in the sense that the coefficients in this quartic are linearly independent regarded as linear functions of $(a, b, c, d, k)$.

Comment: i would consider some special cases eg $$b-d+k=0$$ and $$a=2c$$ or so

Comment: Do you have particular $a,b,c,d,k$ in mind? Say $x=\sin\theta$, $y=\cos\theta$. Then we're looking for intersections of the unit circle and the conic $dx^2-2cxy-dy^2-ax-by+k=0$. Can you tell us what kind of conic this is or could it be several?

Comment: @Trold Thanks. The geometrical intuition about intersections of a unit circle and conic sections would certainly be useful. This problem comes from trying to design an algorithm for cars. $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $k$ depend on the dimensions of the car that the algorithm is running on. I want the algorithm to work for various cars. So I do not have particular values of these parameters. But I can come up with ranges for these values, e.g. a car's width is positive, and smaller than its length. I will try to see if such reasonable assumptions can lead to a characterization of the conic type.

Comment: @Trold Because $(cos \, \theta) ^2 + (sin \, \theta) ^2 = 1$, one always eliminate either  $(cos \, \theta) ^2$ or $ (sin \, \theta) ^2$. Hence the $4AC$ term in the discriminant of conic sections can always be made 0. In my case, I surely know that $c$ is nonzero. Hence, the $B^2$ term in the discriminant is positive. Hence, it is a hyperbola. I guess I now have to rotate and translate axes to get to a hyperbola in the normal form, and then see where it intersects with the unit circle. If you post your answer as a comment, I can accept it.

Comment: I've put up an answer, but I'd recommend doubling check my algebra in getting to the hyperbola since I can be a bit careless sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=\sin\theta$, $y=\cos\theta$ and get the conic

$$ax+by+2cxy+dx^2-dy^2=k,$$ which has solutions to your equation where it intersects the unit circle.

Since $(2c)^2-4d(-d)=4(c^2+d^2)>0$, we're looking at a hyperbola. (In fact, since the coefficients of $x^2$ and y^2$ are negatives of eachother, we're looking at a hyperbola whose asymptotes intercept at right angles.)

Everything is still kind of a mess though.  If we rotate by $\frac{\arctan(-d/c)}{2}$ we should get a hyperbola that has its asymptotes running parallel to the new $u$- and $v$- coöridinate axes with equation $2c'uv+b'u+a'v=k$, which, after some more poking is

$$\left(u-\frac{-a'}{2c'}\right)\left(v-\frac{-b'}{2c'}\right)=\frac{2c'k+a'b'}{4c'^2}. $$
If the center of the hyperbola is very far away from the unit circle you can probably check for intersection just by checking if the asymptotes intersect and then looking nearby.

Comment: The step needed after rotation by $-\frac\pi4$ does not seem right. For a generaly conic section, the rotation needed to get rid of the $xy$ term is $\theta$ such that $cot \, 2\theta= \frac{A-C}{B}$ . $-\frac\pi4$ would have worked if $A$ were equal to $C$. Unfortunately, they are negatives of each other. I just want to confirm that I did not miss something. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Comment: You didn't miss anything, that's my error. I'll see if the rotation can still produce a usable hyperbola and edit the answer if so.

Comment: Updated the answer to not be wrong. Rather than get rid of the $xy$ term I picked the angle so that $d'=d\cos2\psi+c\sin2\psi$ was zero and you're dealing with what, in the new coordinates, is essentially a translation of $v=k/u$.